# arrow head on d3v4 axis

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js

i made a graph using d3v4 everything is working fine. There is a only one issue i am not able to add arrow head on my graph axix. I tried google solution but none of these working for me
Here is my code

```
var svg = d3
  .select("body")
  .append("svg")
  .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
  .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
  .append("g") //add group to leave margin for axis
  .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

svg
  .append("defs")
  .append("marker")
  .attr("id", "arrowhead")
  .attr("refX", 6 + 3)
  .attr("refY", 2)
  .attr("markerWidth", 13)
  .attr("markerHeight", 9)
  // .attr("orient", "right")
  .append("path")
  .attr("d", "M2,2 L2,13 L8,7 L2,2");

var yScale = d3.scaleLinear().rangeRound([0, height]).domain([5, -5]); 
var xScale = d3.scaleLinear().rangeRound([0, width]).domain([-5, 5]); 
var yAxis = d3
  .axisLeft(yScale)
  .tickFormat((d) => (d !== 0 ? EVALUATION_Y[getIndexNumber(d)] : null));
const y = svg
  .append("g")
  .call(yAxis)
  .attr("transform", "translate(" + width / 2 + ",0)")
  .selectAll("text")
  .attr("dx", (d) => (d > 0 ? "-6em" : "2em"))
  .style("text-anchor", "start");
var xAxis = d3
  .axisBottom(xScale)
  .tickFormat((d) => (d !== 0 ? EVALUATION_X[getIndexNumber(d)] : null));

var x = svg
  .append("g")
  .call(xAxis)
  .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height / 2 + ")")
  .selectAll("text")
  .style("text-anchor", "end")
  .attr("dx", (d) => (d < 0 ? "-.8em" : "4em"))
  .attr("dy", "-0.7em")
  .attr("marker-end", "url(#arrow)")
  .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)");

x.select("path").attr("marker-end", "url(#arrow)");
```

[image]

Comment: Because the marker's id is `arrowhead`, and you try to reference it with `arrow`?